# Youtube API - how to get video with custom controls for iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm working on an application that eventually will be uploaded to the App-Store so every solution you suggest has to be legit with licenses against Youtube and Apple.

I'm trying to create a custom video player for Youtube, which will have my own play/pause/stop and next/previous buttons. I've searched quite a lot for legit ways to make this and have not found the correct way yet.

The way I'm using it at the moment is with the Youtube embed player and the parameters:

```
controls = 0,
playsinline = 1,
autohide = 1,
showinfo = 0,
modestbranding = 1
```

With all that, I still have a play button on top of the video.

I've seen the iPhone application called "iTube" and they have their custom controls over youtube without the play button on top of the video. In addition, the looks and feels of the video over there doesn't suits me like the Youtube embed API. It just feels different.

Does anyone know how did they make that?

Comment: Don't think the down vote is necessary but do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well after some more research I've found that they probably used MPMoviePlayerViewController with custom controls.

It uses progressive download so I think they're using it with low quality over cellular networks to not violate Apple's terms.

If anyone thinks differently I would appreciate any response.

Thanks all!